# Rails, implementing voting system that only allows 1 upvote/downvote per user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, where-clause, vote

Can someone tell me why this code doesn't work? On my local server for testing, it keeps flashing "You have already upvoted this" when I haven't.

This is in my code for the votes controller.

```
  def upvote
    @vote = Vote.find(params[:post_id])

    if current_user.votes.where(post_id: params[:post_id], value: 1)
      flash[:notice] =  "You have already upvoted this!"
      redirect_to :back
    else
      @vote.update_attributes(value: 1)
      @vote.user_id = current_user.id
    end
  end
```

Is the 4th line `if current_user.votes.where(post_id: params[:post_id], value: 1)` the correct way to implement the where method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`exists?`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#existence-of-objects)

```
if current_user.votes.where(post_id: params[:post_id], value: 1).exists?
```

If you use only `current_user.votes.where(...)`, you get a `Relation` object that will always be interpreted as a `true` value in the `if`, even if tyhe `Relation` do not match any line (only `false` and `nil` are considered as falsy values in Ruby).